# Ordnance survey obtain property UPRN

Tags: ordnance-survey

I'm digging through the docs here: https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs.

How can I obtain a property UPRN given a valid UK address using a GET request?  Which API can i use?  When you try adding some of the APIs to a project, you can't see them.  I'm assuming they're premium.

I'm also guessing I'd want to search using property number and postcode to return a UPRN?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [linked identifiers overview](https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/linkedIdentifiers/overview) it looks like you need the
AddressBase Premium product.

> An address location with postal address. BLPU stands for Building Land Parcel Unit. UPRN stands for Unique Property Reference Number

Actually searching for an address looks like it could be some work though:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll take a look.  Seems a lot of digging for something that I'd have thought should be relatively trivial tbh....